# update OSX Yosemite & cksum mismatch

Tags: macos

After OSX Update -> Yosemite:
No option to login and run the system.

Via Firewire (T) and Diskutils && Diskwarrior:
"Unvalid Disk-Label @ 499239710720: cksum mismatch"

Diskwarrior: no option to rebuild
Diskutills: Unvalid Disk-Label @ 499239710720: cksum mismatch

What could I do to reboot and rerun the machine? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Recovery - Cmd/R at the chimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have invalid Yosemite Installer package.

Try the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during boot to recover it from Internet.

To check the flie run following in the Terminal

```
shasum /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

The result should be:

```
eebf02a20ac27665a966957eec6f5e6fe3228a19  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

Do this before running the Install.

Comment: thx. the solution was a reinstall of yosemite -> it works.

Comment: -bash: shasum: command not found

Comment: @LarryJohn is your `PATH` not set correctly? Try `/usr/bin/shasum /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg` instead. Sounds like you have an issue with your `PATH` environment variable.