# Disk Utility: Invalid Disk Label @ cksum mismatch

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have a WD external hard drive. I've been running the routine tests to make sure all my stuff is safe lately. In Disk Utility, I did Verify Disk on both the disk itself as well as the main partition, which is in the encrypted HD format.

I ran across this error on the *partition*:

> Invalid Disk Label @[number] cksum mismatch

Which didn't seem very good. Resources online have close to no information, and I don't know what this is. It went away after I scanned again, but that is a common occurrence and other posters said that I should keep an eye on it.

I ran Repair Disk and it went without a hitch, but Verify Disk after that still showed the error.

I ran SMART Utility with the SAT-SMART Driver to enable SMART on external USB drives, it passed with 0 bad sectors and stuff.

Any ideas?

MacBook Air - Mavericks 10.9.5

Comment: Saw that, but this is on normal use on Mavericks (not after upgrade), and not on the main hard drive but an external. Updated description to add Mavericks.

Comment: I can find a lot of refs on Google, back to Lion -  not one seems to have a happy ending for the drive in question. I'd be seriously tempted to back it up/clone to another drive & then see if it can be fixed, rather than the other way round

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look @Tetsujin! Thing is, this drive is also mirrored to another drive but ... that drive also has the same exact problem. I'm starting to think it's a certain file that is causing the checksum mismatch.

Comment: Possibly. It's not an error i actually can find the true cause of; maybe a workaround would be file-copy rather than 'clone'. I'm really not sure, sorry.

Comment: @yotero Is your external device a RAID?

Comment: @klanomath it is not - I plug both in and sync them with Chronosync, which copies files over that were updated.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yotero is right. That's no duplicate of [yosemite-cksum-mismatch](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151261/update-osx-yosemite-cksum-mismatch)

Comment: @klanomath Yes, I realised afterwards, but couldn't retract my flag; had to wait for someone higher up to unflag it.